# create-react-app, proxy and post request

Tags: reactjs, axios, create-react-app

I have a react app currently being made, it's on localhost:3000, it uses an api from a different internet site. "proxy" is defined correctly in my package.json. I can GET a json file from this server. However I cannot POST it. Here is a a look at my code :

```
axios.post('/dir1/dir2/test.json', data)
  .then(response => {
        console.log("response")
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Here is test.json

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $jsonContents;
```

I looked at chrome's debugger to see what was going on, and it makes 4 request to the json I want to POST.

1. GET request to http://localhost:3000/dir1/dir2/test.json
2. POST request to http://localhost:3000/dir1/dir2/test.json
3. OPTIONS request to http://myserver.tld/dir1/dir2/test.json
4. GET request to http://myserver.tld/dir1/dir2/test.json

so my questions are :
why is there a GET request first ?
why does it feel compelled to finally issue a GET instead of a POST request ?

PS: it works perfectly if I ask directly for http://myserver.tld/dir1/dir2/test.json

Comment: It seems you're running into the CORS issue on the server side. You need to have some config in place to allow post for non-origin requests.

Comment: Do you have a solution yet? I have the same problem.

Comment: IIRC: my proxy wasnt set up properly. I cant remember exactly the problem, but I changed the proxy settings in package.json, and then I put it back. Maybe something as stupid as forgotting the s to https from the proxy setting. I should have answered me back then ^^'